Blazor Server OIDC Logout with Keycloak Redirects but Session Not Cleared
have a Blazor Server application configured with OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication using Keycloak. Login works fine and I can authenticate successfully. However, when I log out, I get redirected to the Keycloak logout page but upon returning to my Blazor application, I find that I'm still logged in, even though the Keycloak session is expired.
Here are the details of my setup:
Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LogoutService>();

// Configure logging
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

// Configure OIDC authentication
var oidcSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OIDC");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
    {
        e.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    };
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess);
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.Authority = oidcSettings["Authority"];
    options.ClientId = oidcSettings["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = oidcSettings["ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
    options.RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");
    options.SignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = oidcSettings["Authority"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = oidcSettings["ClientId"],
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };

    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.AddPolicy("AnonymousPolicy", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(_ => true));
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();


appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "OIDC": {
    "Authority": "https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm",
    "ClientId": "myclientid",
    "ClientSecret": "myclientsecret",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7029/",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "SignOutPath": "/signout-oidc"
  }
}

Razor Page
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <button @onclick="Logout">Logout</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <button @onclick="Login">Login</button>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private void Login()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7029/signin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid");
    }

    private void Logout()
    {
        var authority = Configuration["OIDC:Authority"];
        var postLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["OIDC:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        var logoutUrl = $"{authority}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id=myclientid&post_logout_redirect_uri={Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/")}";
        Navigation.NavigateTo(logoutUrl, true);
    }
}

Problem Description:
Login works and redirects successfully to the application.
Logging out redirects to the Keycloak logout page, but when I return to the application, I'm still logged in.
The session in Keycloak is expired but the Blazor application still recognizes the user as logged in.

https://danieldonbavand.com/2024/04/10/securing-digital-identities-streamlining-authentication-with-aws-cognito-in-blazor-net-8-applications/ resolved the issue. As per the OP.
